# What left hand technique is being used to create this percussive chord transition sound?

Tags: guitar, technique, chords, acoustic-guitar, chord-progressions

There is a strange chord transition that I cannot figure out how to play near the beginning of this acoustic guitar song:

(I am guessing) He seems to be playing the following progression in standard tuning relative to a capo on the 3rd fret, with 1 measure (4 beats) given to each chord:

`X|X|5|3|0|5`

`X|X|5|2|0|5`

`X|X|3|2|0|4`

`X|X|2|3|3|1`

or:

```
Am aug5 (F maj)
Am
F
G
```

Just a little after the timepoint I linked to, he somehow transitions between G and F such that a subtle percussive noise is generated. How can this noise be consistently reproduced?

Comment: I think it's "down-up, up-down-up" but it's not quite clear which part you're referring to.

Comment: Yes, please add some specifics, this is a cool song. We want to help you play it.

Comment: This question has a couple of "too localized" close votes on it already.  I have voted to close as "not a real question", as I think right now it's a bit too vague (as evidenced by the other comments, and the answers).  If you would like a high quality answer, please consider adding more details to this post about what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sometimes using hammer-ons while changing chords can create a nice "percussiony" sound, I dont know if its what your looking for as i cant see the video on the computer i am currently using. also looking at the slap technique on bass-guitar, there are similar things that can be done by literally slapping your thumb on the string but this often requires a nice fingerpicking technique.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern more or less throughout the song is:

- Place left hand
- Pick bass note
- Down strum
- Up strum
- Quiet down strum
- Change left hand slightly (generally one finger pulling off)
- Up strum

This site isn't a transcription service, so we won't work out the exact chords for you; you might find a tab or a chord sheet on one of the tab sites.

Answer (score -1):

While strumming there are a couple of chord changes in there (as Matthew said- it would help if you explained which one you were interested in) where the guitarist first changes the bass note on the down strum, hammers on another note but then doesn't change the rest of the chord until the next beat.